# Using the predicted values of one regression as the dependent variable in another; problems? techniques?

Tags: regression, econometrics

Forgive me if this question is redundant; predicted values and regression returns many results.

My question is this:

I would like to run one regression and generate predicted values based upon a subset of the variables in that regression. With these predicted values I then want to regress them on other variables.

Multi-level modelling is similar to the task, but I specifically need the predicted values as opposed to the coefficients. Based upon this strategy, would I need to do anything with the error structure in the second regression? FGLS with a het correction based upon the subset of variables seems reasonable. But i'm out of my depths in terms of theory.

Tia.

Comment: They're neither constant variance nor independent, so you may want to consider those issues.